# Run "sudo vulkaninfo" at startup, all users

Tags: boot, scripts

I need to run the command `sudo vulkaninfo` each time the system starts up (I know how to do it when system wakes up from sleep, i.e. in `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/somescript`). This command should be global, so all users will run this command at startup. I tried adding a script to profile.d under /etc/profile.d, but that resulted in me not being able to login. rc.local is only local, so that will not work. What options do I have?

**Edit**: I need to be able to do this from a terminal, as I am creating a script that automates my system setup, so programs will not work. So for example I need a command that can create the file, append the command and move the file to where system startup files are located.

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: is cron for all users?

Answer (score 1):

I’d use root’s crontab with `@reboot` for that, it can easily be edited from a root script:

```
(crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "@reboot vulkaninfo") | crontab -
```

This adds the line `@reboot vulkaninfo` to root’s crontab, which runs `vulkaninfo` with root permissions on every boot.

Note that cron has a minimal environment, if your command needs environment variables set either set them manually or source a file which sets them, e.g. `$HOME/.profile`. The command might also be executed too early in the startup process, a simple `sleep` command or a testing loop are ways around that.

Further reading:

- [How to run scripts on start up?](https://askubuntu.com/q/814/507051)
- [How do I create a crontab through a script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9625233/6164712)
- [How can I run a cron command with existing environmental variables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/27289/246819)